# CSS Grid - Understanding the Grid for Text

Tags: css, grid

I'm Starting to use CSS GRID. My problem is that the article text isn't expanding the whole div but only uses 300px or so in the left side. I don't know why. It is probably because of ...these two values ( grid-template-rows and grid-template-columns. Im not sure how you use them.

grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 30px;
 grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;

Codepen: https://codepen.io/stephyswe/pen/mwYbyy

```css
#article {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  grid-template-areas: "head head head"
                        "desc desc desc"
                       "jour-pic jour-name jour-name"
                       "star article extra";
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 30px;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
}

#article > #headline {
  grid-area: head;
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
}

#article > #description {
  grid-area: desc;
  background-color: #ffa08c;
}

#article > #jour-pic {
  grid-area: jour-pic;
  background-color: #afa08c;
}

#article > #jour-name {
  grid-area: jour-name;
  background-color: #ffff64;
}

#article > #star {
  grid-area: star;
  background-color: #ffff64;
}

#article > #article {
  grid-area: article;
  background-color: red;
}

#article > #extra {
  grid-area: extra;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas -->

<section id="article">
  <div id="headline">headline</div>
  <div id="description">description</div>
  <div id="jour-pic">journalist pic</div>
    <div id="jour-pic">journalist pic</div>
    <div id="jour-name">journalist textjournalist textjournalist textjournalist textjournalist textjournalist textjournalist textjournalist textjournalist text</div>
    <div id="star">star</div>
  <div id="article">article text article text article text article text article textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle textarticle text</div>
  <div id="extra">extra stuff</div>
</section>
```

Edit: Nevermind. Apparently. it was a human error. I gave the section and div the same name. That's so embarrassing.

Comment: You have your grid-template-columns set to 150px so the text only fills to the width of the column.

Comment: How would a solution look @JacobH ?

Comment: I'm trying to use
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 1fr 7fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
@ https://codepen.io/stephyswe/pen/mwYbyy . =) . Im not sure about how the grid really works.

Comment: Well it's a  2 part problem, you have two areas named `article` so the style is being applied to both. I will post a solution.

Comment: On Codepen: https://codepen.io/stephyswe/pen/mwYbyy Im just using "Xfr" values now. But the article text is still locked in the left corner. Not sure why. Oh do I ?. OMG!... i named the div the same name as the section. WTF :D

Comment: That so embarrassing.

Comment: No problem, it's still somewhat early on a Monday I think we all get a pass until at least Tuesday ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a section and div both named `article` which is throwing off your css. I updated your code to fix that by renaming your article div to "article2" and referencing that in the CSS as #article2.

HTML:

```
 <div id="article2">...</div>
```

CSS:

```
#article > #article2 {
  grid-area: article;
  background-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xzfj4yct/